# Azure RTOS how to signal multiples thread with single event?

Tags: multithreading, embedded, software-design, threadx, azure-rtos

I want to signal multiple threads with one event, what is the best way to do this? For example:
Whenever 1 second passes, RTC interrupt occurs and it sets its related event flag, after that whichever thread waits for this event, starts running, and does its job.

```
RTC interrupt:    
    tx_event_flags_set (&rtc_events, 1_SEC_PASS, TX_OR);

1st Thread: 
    tx_event_flags_get (&rtc_events, 1_SEC_PASS, TX_OR_CLEAR, &flag_val, TX_WAIT_FOREVER);

2nd Thread: 
    tx_event_flags_get (&rtc_events, 1_SEC_PASS, TX_OR_CLEAR, &flag_val, TX_WAIT_FOREVER);
```

If I use it like that, only one of the threads will be notified. I can use multiple event flags for the same RTC event, but this time RTC would be dependent on the threads and this will be bad in terms of loose coupling.

```
RTC interrupt:    
    tx_event_flags_set (&first_thread_events, 1_SEC_PASS, TX_OR);
    tx_event_flags_set (&second_thread_events, 1_SEC_PASS, TX_OR);

1st Thread: 
    tx_event_flags_get (&first_thread_events, 1_SEC_PASS, TX_OR_CLEAR, &flag_val, TX_WAIT_FOREVER);

2nd Thread: 
    tx_event_flags_get (&second_thread_events, 1_SEC_PASS, TX_OR_CLEAR, &flag_val, TX_WAIT_FOREVER);
```

Which of these methods would be best? Is there any third way to solve this problem, in terms of better software design? Or am I worrying too much?

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

The event flags are a pretty basic concept and are not really suitable for notifying multiple threads (such as your first example).

Your second example is the correct way to go, you want a flag for each thread that is to be updated.

If your application requires further decoupling, then you would be would likely want to move to some form of publish/subscribe model, where they threads can explicitly subscribe to the messages they are interested in, and the RTC thread would publish the message.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A publish/subscribe model will increase the complexity of the application but it's a better way. Can you share an example in c for such a model, please?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan is correct. You can also have multiple flags within one group, i.e. you do not need to create 2 groups like you do in your second example.